# How do I block Duplicate Entries based on a particular field in Google Forms

Tags: forms-authentication, google-forms

How do I block Duplicate Entries based on a particular field in Google Forms (For Eg: I am Collecting Contact Details and I don't Want duplicate entries based on Mobile Numbers)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no option or built-in feature that checks and prevents duplicate field entries for Google Forms.

As a workaround, although it won't prevent the user to submit a identical value, you could do some validations using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) and delete duplicates from there. Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16965687/4625829).